# Does Minecraft on PS3 support remote play?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

If I buy Minecraft for my PS3, am I able to play it on my PS Vita using remote play?

I want to buy it this Christmas so I haven't been able to it myself yet.

Comment: I don't know about Remote Play, but there is a PS Vita version of Minecraft.

Comment: According to [Mojang's blog](https://mojang.com/2013/12/minecraft-playstation-3-edition-is-now-available/), information about Remote Play will arrive around New Years. I suspect this means, no, there is no Remote Play support yet, but there might be in the future.